# Can date() be compared like this?

Tags: php, date

I have had some issues with comparing date/times.

I had a working code that just stopped working all of a sudden. Now I made some changes to it and by some reason UNIX time is not correct.

Utime and nexttime is just an example string now, but in the code Utime is last time updated, and nexttime is next time a update will happen calculated from Utime.

Example:

```
 $Utime = "201603300450"; // YmdHi 2016 03 30 04:50
 $nexttime = "201603300520"; 
 if (date("YmdHi")>=$Utime && date("YmdHi")>=$nexttime)
```

Is this a safe way to compare the timevalue? I had some issues with strtotime thats why I ask.

Comment: How did  you use strtotime then?

Comment: whats the issue with strtotime ?

Comment: This is how the If looked: if (strtotime(date("YmdHi"))>=strtotime($Utime) && strtotime(date("YmdHi"))>=strtotime($nexttime)) ||||||| The issue was that $nexttime was a higher value than "now" even if the date and time was lower.

Comment: problem with summer time ?

Comment: Sorry I mean the other way around. Nexttime was lower than now

Comment: Don't know if it's summer time. But both times as in UTC, date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); is set above all calculations

Comment: Why not use `strtotime($Utime)` ?

Comment: @Chris ? Sorry, where?

Comment: Check out my answer. strtotime is a great helper for something like this.

Comment: The problem is that strtotime did not work. It gave me the wrong output, thus stopping the update

Comment: The reason for this being that your date is seen as an integer and is not a time string. strtotime is a time string read as integer. if you surrounded your dates in a strtotime as well, you would have had the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your dates to `DateTime` objects:

```
<?php

$Utime = "201603300450";
$nexttime = "201603300520";

$dateUtime = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', $Utime);
$datenexttime = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', $nexttime);

$nowDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', date('YmdHi'));

if ($nowDate>=$dateUtime && $nowDate>=$datenexttime)
    //do your stuff...
```

Comment: Uh oh! You stopped me answering half way through! Just that this one is not correctly being built `$nowDate`

Comment: Looks good. Will try it..

Comment: Wait it has a problem :) Let's get that fixed first then you should try it. Without that fix it will not work and you'll be put off

Answer (score 0):

Strtotime should work just fine, but you should stick to a valid format. "Y-m-d H:i:s" is a valid format for strtotime.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So I have to use that format for it to work?

Comment: Nope you don't necessarily have to use that format

Answer (score -2):

strtotime() is a great helper in this regard.

Check out [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$Utime = "201603300450";
$nexttime = "201603300520";
if ( strtotime('now') >= strtotime($Utime) && strtotime('now') >= strtotime($nexttime) )
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code I posted above in the comments, that did not work.

Comment: It is not the same as you were still messing with date functions. I very simply use now and a valid date format and viola !